# Subscription Code Firing off Incrementally Every Time Component Loads

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In my component's `ngOnInit` I have the following:

```
public Subscription: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription =  this.myService.currentData.subscribe( i => {
        this.currentData = i;
        this.function(this.currentData)
    });
}
```

When my component loads, I have it subscribe to some data in a service to later use in a function. Loading it the first time works great. However, when I load to another module then come back, the function will fire off two times. Every time I repeat this process the function will fire off and increment. Meaning if I switch in and out of the module say 5 times, the function will fire off 5 times.

My attempt at solving this was to add an unsubscribe to `ngOnDestroy` like so:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

However this seems to do nothing as the issue still occurs.

Comment: Seems that your component is being recreated so `ngOnInit` will also execute which calls the service end point. This would be expected behavior (IMO). If this is not what is happening you should provide an [mcve] that better illustrates the problem. I recommend using https://stackblitz.com

Comment: Yes you are correct, my component is being recreated, however, shouldn't my `ngOnDestroy` code account for this?

Comment: `ngDestroy` would run on that instance but when it is recreated the new instance of that component will have `ngOnInit` be called again.

Comment: If that is the case, shouldn't the function only ever fire off once?

Comment: What is `currentData` in your service?  From the sounds of it, it is acting like a `ReplaySubject` ...

Comment: It is an object from a custom made class.

Comment: I actually had this exact same problem today. I subscribed to a `Subject` from a service in a component that would intermittently be destroyed and recreated, just like you are describing. However, putting the unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy` **did** fix my problem, so I don't know how my situation differs from yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues were present. First off, I was declaring my Subscription incorrectly.

Instead of this:

```
public Subscription: Subscription;
```

This is what needs to be put:

```
public Subscription = new Subscription();
```

Also, instead of equating my Subscription to my subscribe statement, I switched to .add(). This allows me to have my subscription object be assigned to all subscribers and unsubscribe them in one go:

```
this.Subscription.add(this.myService.currentData.subscribe( i => {
    this.currentData = i;
    this.function(this.currentData)
}));
```